# What are we going to do with this unclear question about django and play apps for nontechnical clients?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

There's a question that was asked on our site that's now closed.

[Must I use cPanel-based hosting providers for applications I built for a client where I don't want to manage things after deployment?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2300/django-and-play-apps-for-non-technical-clients)

The question was closed because it's not clear what the asker is asking. What's more, it doesn't seem like it's on topic, since it's a technical question, something that would be better served on Programmers SE or Stack Overflow.

One user answered it, and the asker marked it as the accepted answer. However, neither of these are positively scored, which indicates that perhaps only the asker found it valuable.

Since our goal is to be the best place on the Internet for freelancing problems, our content must be something that others can easily relate to and find in searches. If this post doesn't do that, it may need to be removed.  However, if anyone sees what it is that the asker is asking, you have the power to save the post by editing the question to help the asker make the post more clear.  Any edits will make this post more valuable to future visitors and create value on our site.

Does anyone want to try making an edit? If you have questions or want to bounce around editing ideas, use the answers below. Let's save this post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks acceptable. I have it a quick skim, but I don't see any startling issues with it. I can understand what they're asking, even though I don't know the specific technologies.

If I'm wrong, then feel free to correct me. I would vote to reopen, but I'd like the community's input first.

Comment: Some people see it as a programming question. while others see it as a freelancing question. However, what I see is a question that just asks "Does anyone have experience with this?" and something vague about "getting rid of a client" and whether that will be enough. Well, will *what* be enough?  To me, it seems the question could be reorganized a little better. But even then, the big question is wouldn't questions about architecture and cPanels be off-topic on a site for problems specific to freelancing?

Comment: I think the first step might be just an edit to reorganize the content so the questions are all together. That would definitely help us all take a more objective look at what's there.

Comment: He's not asking a programming question. He's asking how to get rid of the client cleanly, and if after-project support should be included in the cost. I'm not seeing where it's programming related. For the 'is it enough' section, I would not close it based on that part alone. As he states, English isn't his native language, but we understand what he means: if he sets it up right the first time and tells him he won't provide extra support, is it the end of dealing with the client. It's not about the cPanel, it's about dealing with the client and their "choices" in technology.

Comment: It's the English not native thing that might be part of the problem. Can we clean that up? I'll give it an editing go later on, but I think the key takeaway from this, from what I understand you're saying, is that it's a good question, it just needs some copy editing. I think we as a community need to do more of this type of editing so more people can (1) find the content via search and (2) understand the content. Otherwise, we're leaving a lot of broken windows on our site and limiting our reach in the broader freelancing community.

Comment: I went ahead and reopened, as it now looks great!

Answer (score 0):

I gave this an edit to improve and clarify the post.  I started by making a stronger  reference to the previous post, so this stands out on its own without requiring people to read the previous question.

I also clarified the information about the difference between using a cPanel and using Django and Play Framework. Spelling the names correctly, with proper capitalization, helps make it more clear what these are.

Afterwards, I clarified the questions at the end so it was more clear that the asker is looking to disengage with the client, once the work is done, and not be stuck maintaining the infrastructure.

Lastly, I fixed the title, making it more specific to the situation.

Can this be edited even more to clarify it further, perhaps making it more concise? Anyone can make suggested edits on a post, and anyone with [1000 reputation can edit any post in the system](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).

Should this be reopened? If you have at least [500 reputation to cast close/reopen votes](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), consider [voting to reopen the question](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2300/django-and-play-apps-for-non-technical-clients).